# Samsung j5 won't connect to wifi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung

My Samsung won't connect to wifi anywhere. A few days ago a message came up saying something about third parties, monitoring and being able to access app data. Ever since no internet with wifi or data. Everything else seems to be working well.

Appreciate any help, thanks.